# Python array as a counter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a Python 3.0 beginner and I'm struggling to find a solution to the following problem. It's a step for a Galton Board simulation exercise.

1. I have an numpy array, which length is auto generated based on another variable
2. I am then generating a set of numbers, adding them to a list and summing them
3. I would finally want to add a counter of +1 to the array index, which equals the number in the sum in step 2.

```
import numpy as np
import random as rnd

zufall = rnd.randint(0,1)
zufall_list = []
hoehe = int(input("Höhe? "))
behaelter = np.zeros(hoehe+1, int)


for i in range(hoehe):
    zufall_list.append(rnd.randint(0,1))

    for j in str(sum(zufall_list)):
        behaelter[j] += 1
print(zufall_list)
```

I get an `IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (None) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices` error and don`t understand why that is.

Comment: You're indexing `behaelter` with a string. Not any of the valid ones you've listed above.

Comment: In your inner for loop you convert your sum of `zufall_list` to `str`, probably so you can iterate over the individual digits of the resulting number. However these are still str. Try `behaelter[int(j)] += 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for j in str(sum(zufall_list)):
    behaelter[j] += 1
```

In this line, you are using str(sum(...)), a string as index. Although string is iterable, it cannot be used as an index.

In your case, I would do behaelter[int(j)] to change 'j' into an integer so that you can use it as an index.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
for j in str(sum(zufall_list)):
    behaelter[j] += 1
```

use

```
for j in str(sum(zufall_list)):
    behaelter[int(j)] += 1
```